# Unable to fire click event even after using $compile

Tags: angularjs

```
//Directive for adding buttons on click that show an alert on click
app.directive("addbuttons", function($compile){
    return function(scope, element, attrs){
        element.bind("click", function(){

            angular.element(document.getElementById('stopList')).append($compile("<md-list-item  class='md-3-line'  style='background:rgb(233, 233, 233);margin:10px;padding-left: 10px;position: relative;min-height: 60px;'><div class='md-list-item-text'><h3>"+scope.name+"</h3><h4>"+scope.noOfStudents+"</h4></div><div ng-click='showConfirm($event)' class='delete_icon'></div></md-list-item>")(scope));
        });
    };
});
```

In above code I've written ng-click='showConfirm($event)' in a div but it doest get fired after adding it to DOM.

Comment: Are you sure `showConfirm()` is on the scope? Also, you're injecting compile, which is unnecessary. `compile` is part of the directive API, see https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile. To me it looks a lot, like you're trying to use Angular like jQuery.

Comment: yeah and it is inside controller scope... and I've added $compile in above code you can see

Comment: As I said, injecting `$compile` is not necessary, since it's part of the directive API. You can use `template` to compile and add a template to the DOM (instead of appending it using jQuery). Check this example, for how this might work: http://codepen.io/minuskruste/pen/wKxMzp?editors=101

Comment: But I have to dynamically add this element through controller..in your solution I will have to add  <list-confirm></list-confirm> inside view. I cant have this element as static